# Pointing a subdomain (subdomain.example.com) to a subfolder (example.com/subfolder)?

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain

I want my subdomain `subdomain.example.com` to load content from a subfolder on the root domain `example.com/subfolder`.

So if a user goes to `subdomain.example.com/?article=hey` it should load the content from `domain.com/subfolder/?article=hey`.

Web server: Apache

Comment: What web server? If Apache, this should be possible. Your example, domain.com/subfolder?article=hey may better appear as domain.com/subfolder/?article=hey. Is that what you want? If both are on the same server with Apache, you can change DocumentRoot and Directory directives of the sub-domain to point where ever you want. As well, you can always use a symlink so that the DocumentRoot and Directory of the sub-domain are in fact what you want. I prefer the first method of course.

Comment: How are you creating the subdomain? Are you using a hosting control panel of some kind eg. cPanel?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Apache then you can simply create an additional VirtualHost for your sub domain and set the webroot to the directory you choose.

---

**Example**:

Your current VirtualHost is most likely something along the lines of the following; with the `ServerName` your domain and the `DocumentRoot` being the web root.

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/domain"
</VirtualHost>
```

You could create another VirtualHost with the `ServerName` as the sub domain and the `DocumentRoot` as the sub folder you want to use such as this:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/domain/subfolder"
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when you access `subdomain.example.com` in your browser it would load the content from `/www/domain/subfolder`. Keep in mind that in this example you would still be able to access the sub folder by going to `www.example.com/subfolder` since the sub folder is still within the first VirtualHosts `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: Seems like a good solution, could that be done in .htaccess as well for a solution that could be moved easily with a site when moved to other hosts et cetera?

Comment: VirtualHosts can not be done with htaccess it would have to be done within the apache conf. file. But if you need to use htaccess you might be able to do this with a redirect if you have a wildcard DNS setup or just make sure that the subdomain is also pointed to the same address. Here is a question on SO that might get the results you want - http://stackoverflow.com/q/10642426/2268476

Comment: @PetaspeedBeaver "a solution that could be moved easily with a site" - The creation of the subdomain in the first place isn't necessarily something that can be "moved easily with a site". Incidentally, on hosts that use cPanel then this is the default behaviour when you create a subdomain.